# Getting string between to markers in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a text file and I would like to get the string between two markers.

`*rdfs:label         "Henry Dunant"@de , "Henry Dunant"@en , "Henri Dunant"@fr ;*`

This is the piece of text, I would like to get only the string `"Henry Dunant"@en` so I get Henry Dunant

So everything between `"` and `"@en`

Comment: Try this one: "([\w\s]+)"@en

Comment: You're probably looking for python's re module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: The string being parsed here is RDF in the Turtle format, so you should use a Turtle parser. Python's RDFLib (https://pypi.org/project/rdflib/) will parse this string, assuming it's part of a larger, valid Turtle string, into an in-memory graph which can then be queried via its API. g.parse(turtle_string, format="turtle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get one word, you can try the following code:

```
str_text = "rdfs:label         \"Henry Dunant\"@de , \"Henry Dunant\"@en , \"Henri Dunant\"@fr ;"
splitted_text = str_text.split("\"")
word = ""
for ind, fragment in enumerate(splitted_text):
    if fragment[:3]=="@en":
        word=splitted_text[ind-1]
print(word)
```

Result:

```
Henry Dunant
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get required data using regular expression as below

```
import re

source = '*rdfs:label         "Henry Dunant"@de , "Henry Dunant"@en , "Henri Dunant"@fr ;*'
match = re.search(r'"[\w ]+"@en', source).group()
print(match)
```

for more information on regular expression in python, refer [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read the text file and then split it using (',') into a list.
you can use loops to iterate through the elements

make another list to hold the new extracted elements.

```
extracted= []
for rawstring in list:
    for character in rawstring:
        if character == 'firstmarker':
            index1 = rawstring.index(character)
        elif character == 'secondmarker':
            index2 = rawstring.index(character) 
    extracted.append(rawstring[index1+1:index2])
```

You will now have everything in extracted list
put your two markers instead of 'firstmarker' and 'secondmarker'

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it in the simplest way :

```
string = '*rdfs:label         \"Henry Dunant\"@de , \"Henry Dunant\"@en , \"Henri Dunant\"@fr ;*'
res = string.split('\"')
for i in range(len(res)) :
    if res[i] == '@en , ':
        print(res[i-1])
```